# Runtime formula error 1004 swaformula

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a formula error message: Run-time error 1004, for the second recurrence of a formula in the code; the code section in question as follows, for quick reference I pasted the two formulas just below, the first one runs OK, the second one gives the error that I cannot figure out.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="pivotsourceFGPO", RefersToR1C1:=swaFormula (no errors when running the macro)

 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="pivotsourceorderbase", RefersToR1C1:=swaFormula (FORMULA giving error)
```

Code: (partial)

```
swaFormula = "=OFFSET(" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Name & "!R" & ActiveCell.Row & "C" & ActiveCell.Column & ",0,0,COUNTA(" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Name & "!C" & ActiveCell.Column & ") -" & swarow & ",COUNTA(" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Name & "!R" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-" & swacol & ")"

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="pivotsourceFGPO", RefersToR1C1:=swaFormula
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pvtfld As PivotField

' define the range which serves as the data range

Set WS = Sheets.Add ' add new sheet to hold the pivot table
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase,  SourceData:="=pivotsourceFGPO")

' Create the pivot table
Set pt = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WS.Range("A1"), TableName:="FGPOPivot")

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True

pt.PivotFields("Key").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("Key").Position = 1
pt.PivotFields("MTL").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("MTL").Position = 2
pt.PivotFields("Size Code").Orientation = xlRowField
pt.PivotFields("Size Code").Position = 3
pt.PivotFields("Week").Orientation = xlColumnField
pt.PivotFields("Week").Position = 1
pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Wip Qty"), "Sum of Wip Qty", xlSum

'Order base 1 pivot
Sheets("Order base (1)").Select
Range("A1").Select
swarow = ActiveCell.Row - 1
swacol = ActiveCell.Column - 1

' make it comma and not colon
swaFormula = "=OFFSET(" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Name & "!R" & ActiveCell.Row & "C" & ActiveCell.Column & ",0,0,COUNTA(" & _

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Name & "!C" & ActiveCell.Column & ") -" & swarow & ",COUNTA(" & _
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Name & "!R" & ActiveCell.Row & ")-" & swacol & ")"

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="pivotsourceorderbase", RefersToR1C1:=swaFormula (FORMULA giving error)
```

Comment: Guessing `swaFormula` is bad. You're using `activeworkbook/sheet/cell` so are you sure the object you want is active?

Answer (score 3):

You are relying on the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx). There are better ways¹ to reference cells than that but if those 'best practises can be disregarded for a minute, the ActiveCell knows what its [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) worksheet and workbook are.

Additionally, with no actual worksheet names provided, there is no guarantee that the [ActiveSheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx)'s [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) does not contain a space and may require ticks (e.g. `'`) to wrap it. Either those should be added as a matter of course or the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) should be used to generate the strings for the cell range(s).

The non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) could concevably replace the volatile² [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) but I don't know enough about the layout of your data to suggest an infallible substitute formula.

```
Dim swaFormula As String, rngName As String
Dim swaRow As Long, swaCol As Long

rngName = "pivotSourceOrderBase"
swaRow = 0: swaCol = 0

With ActiveCell
    swaFormula = "=OFFSET(" & _
                    .Cells(1).Address(external:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & _
                    ", 0, 0, COUNTA(" & _
                    .Cells(1).EntireColumn.Address(external:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & _
                    ")-" & swaRow & ", COUNTA(" & _
                    .Cells(1).EntireRow.Address(external:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & _
                    ")-" & swaCol & ")"
    Debug.Print swaFormula  '<~~ check the formula in the Immediate window
    On Error Resume Next    'may be needed for the next line
    .Parent.Parent.Names(rngName).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Parent.Names.Add Name:=rngName, RefersToR1C1:=swaFormula
End With
```

Walk through this and check the formula in the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx) before attempting to apply it to the named range creation.

---

¹ <sub>See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.</sub>

² <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>